# Resize the image with fixed height according to the browser's window size

Tags: jquery, css, image

I'm using the following function to resize my images when I resize my browser's window:

```
function resize_image(a){
    $(a).on("load",function(){
        var b;
        var d=$(this).width()/$(this).height();
        var c=$(this).parent().width() / $(this).parent().height();
        if(d<c){
            b={width:"auto",height:"100%"}
        }else{
            b={width:"100%",height:"auto"}
        }
        $(this).css(b)
    })
};
```

That function are only working if you don't have any fixed height or width on the element. I want to have the image in a DIV tag so I can have a background-color/image that indicates that the image is loading, rather than a invisible image (as it is now).

Why I want to have a manual height that have the same height as the image, is because I have some contents under the image. When the website is loading the image, the content are at top of the website (top = 0). When the image has been loaded, the content pops down so it's under the image. I want to prevent this because the image can load a bit slow sometimes because of the web hosting and it looks kinda weird when the content are visible but not the image.

Now to my question. Is it possible to have a manual height in a DIV tag with this function, and the image resizing correctly according to the browser's window size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bit of a hack to reserve space for an image prior it being loaded...

This approach revolves around knowing the aspect ratio of the image, so there are a few things to consider first:

Are the images hardcoded into the page? If so, you can hard-code the aspect ratio in yourself. This is the easiest way.

If the images are dynamic and you *don't* know what the aspect ratio, you will have to use something else to determine the aspect ratio for you. My recommendation would be to utilize PHP's `getimagesize()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php.

For this example, I will assume that you are capable of hard-coding the ratio in.

The technique is detailed fairly thoroughly here:

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/09/16/responsive-images-performance-problem-case-study/

I would recommend giving that a read and ignoring the rest of my post, because it will probably be much more useful. However, here's the summary:

Because the image won't take up any space until it is loaded, you cannot rely on it to create the space. You can, however, utilize padding to reserve a space in advance. To do this, the height of the container element needs to be set to 0, so that the padding is in complete control of the element's height.

Next, you want to set the padding to a percentage that reflects the aspect ratio.

For example, a 16:9 image would have 100% width, and 9/16 of 100% is 56.25%. Therefore, you will apply padding-bottom: 56.25% to the element. It will now reserve a 16:9 block, relative to the width of the container, ignoring the height of the child element. (That is, not adding that child's height to the total height of the element, as it has already been accounted for.)

So, to put that all together, you'd have something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-space">
        <img src="something.jpg" alt="16:9 Image" />
    </div>
    <p>This space is reserved!</p>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
}
.image-space {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Full example:

http://jsfiddle.net/MeyEb/

*note that the random image I grabbed isn't quite the right ratio so you can see the extra space below it. That won't happen if you do it right, though on the plus size, it helps show off the fact that you can put a background on that space behind, and it will be there, and visible even if the image is not.

Comment: Many thanks! But I don't understand how I can resolve one thing from your solution. You wrote, "For example, a 16:9 image would have 100% width, and 9/16 of 100% is 56.25%." I have the aspect ratio of the image but how can I calculate the procent of the aspect ratio out of 100% with pure PHP? I have tried this: `list($first, $second) = explode(':', $aspect); echo (100 - $second / $first).'%';` but that only prints `99.333333333333%` with a aspect ratio of 3:2

Comment: height divided by width, multiplied by 100 will give you the percentage of the height. So you would want something like `$second / $first * 100`.

Comment: Thanks :) That solved that issue but the image will not be resized as I resizing my browser's window. The image is fixed to its full width and height which is 1280x853 with your solution. I have the exact code as you have on your jsFiddle and from here.

Comment: Ensure that the image itself, as well as the container element for the image, are both set to `width: 100%;`. Also, make sure the container element has `position: relative;`, and that the main container that THAT is inside, also has a percentage based width.

Comment: I compared your code with mine and I saw that mine wasn't the same as yours. Now it is the same and the image are resizable with the jQuery function I have in my question. But the image is quite smaller than it should be; http://upload.erik-edgren.nu/image/wrong-size-on-image.jpg. The height are also fixed to what I have set no mather how big or small the window's size are, which is also wrong :/

Comment: If the image is smaller than it should be, it means that the width of one of the containing elements is not properly set, and not spanning the full 100%. I can't help you more without seeing the code. As for the height.. Are you wanting the height to be 100% of the screen as well? If so then your image is going to get stretched out and look terrible... And to do that you don't even need to do all this complicated stuff..

Comment: Ok. I have added a fast example of how it looks like in my code. I added some comments for better understanding. http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/k7VaK/

Comment: I've fixed the issues now! I deleted the height for the container and changed the width from 50% to 100% for the same container. It's working like a charm! Many thanks for your help :)